# SELECT con relación a la misma tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de *issue* con un campo *Id* y un *parent_Id*.

Hay 3 tipos de issue: *Project* - *Task* y *subtask* (además de una tabla *project* con el detalle más macro del proyecto).

Si es *task*, en *parent_id* está el id del proyecto; si es *subtask*, en *parent_id* esta el id de la *task*.

Ahora necesito traer toda las relaciones en una sola tabla.
La query que armé es la siguiente:

```
select i2.`key` subtask,
       i2.id idsubtarea,
       i.`key` task,
       i.id idtask,
       i3.`key` project,
       i3.id idproject
from issue i
inner join issue i2 on i.id= i2.parent_id 
left join project p2 on i.project_id =p2.id
left join issue i3 on i3.id =i.parent_id
```

La salida en el caso que sale bien me arroja esta relación:

```
subtask     idsubtarea  task    idtask  project idproject
IC-275      1373204    IC-259   1370388 IC-4    1260336
IC-276      1373205    IC-259   1370388 IC-4    1260336
IC-277      1373219    IC-259   1370388 IC-4    1260336
IC-278      1373222    IC-259   1370388 IC-4    1260336
```

pero si filtro por otro nombre de proyecto ya no me sirve la relación, no me trae dato del project y su id:

```
subtask idsubtarea  task    idtask  project idproject
EC-14   1371966     EC-13   1371965     
EC-15   1371970     EC-13   1371965     
EC-19   1385933     EC-13   1371965     
EC-21   1387126     EC-20   1387120
```

La ddl de la tabla principal es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `issue` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(191) NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_datetime` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_account_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issuetype` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_subtask` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `labels` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `reporter_account_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignee_account_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `duedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `resolution_datetime` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resolution` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `votes` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_viewed_datetime` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customfields` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_issue_issuetype` (`issuetype`),
  KEY `idx_issue_status` (`status`),
  KEY `idx_issue_key` (`key`),
  KEY `idx_issue_parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `fk_issue_reporter` (`reporter_account_id`),
  KEY `fk_issue_project` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1452931 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Con esta query me pasa que con algunos proyectos sí veo bien la info pero otros ni aparecen.
¿En qué le estoy pifiando?

Comment: Podrías compartir la estructura de las tablas involucradas (preferentemente los CREATE TABLES).

Comment: Es mucho más fácil explicarnos si nos muestras las sentencias DDL de las tablas y algunos datos de prueba para ver qué datos no te aparecen al ejecutar la consulta. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, incluir (no pegar imágenes) del código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias a todos por los comentarios, fui agregando la info, disculpen soy nueva en el foro y en el área.

Comment: No hay problema @roanabel, de a poco iras aprendiendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien el requerimiento.

En tu enunciado mencionas la columna issuetype con valores: 'project', 'task' y 'subtask'; pero nunca la utilizas en tu query.

Además en tu query vinculas con la tabla project (LEFT JOIN) pero no utilizas información de dicha vinculación, por lo tanto estaría de mas.

La siguiente query obtiene las tareas y subtareas (la subtarea aparece relacionada (en la misma fila) con al tarea de la cual depende) del proyecto buscando por el id del proyecto (reemplaza el "?" por el id del proyecto en el WHERE).

```
SELECT 
      i.id AS idproject,
      i.`key` AS project,
      
      i2.id AS idtask,
      i2.`key` AS task,
      
      i3.id AS idsubtarea,
      i3.`key` AS subtask
      
FROM issue i
LEFT JOIN issue i2 ON i2.issuetype = 'task' AND i2.parent_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN issue i3 ON i3.issuetype = 'subtask' AND i3.parent_id = i2.id
WHERE i.id = ?
ORDER BY i.id, i2.id, i3.id;
```

En el WHERE en lugar de filtrar por el id de un proyecto, puedes filtrar por `i.issuetype = 'project'` y te traerá la misma información pero de todos los proyectos que haya.

En lugar de i2 el alias podría ser iTask, y en lugar de i3 iSubtask, o una abreviatura de los mismos.

Comment: Gracias Nacho por la ayuda, corre el modelo de la query que me comentas pero sigue sin traerme la data de las tareas y subtareas :(

Comment: De nada @roanabel! Revisa si los valores de la columna issuetype están escritos tal cual los he escrito yo ('task', 'subtask') respetando mayúsculas y minúsculas; si no es así modifca la query con los valores correctos.

Comment: Lo puedes probar [aquí](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96ff31b1f78576802483500ff1116232).

Comment: Genial Nacho, me sirvió mucho tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada @roanabel! Me alegra haberte ayudado. No olvides seleccionar la respuesta que mejor contesta tu pregunta, así la misma queda marcada como contestada. También puedes votar mas de una respuesta.